# SQL Server update trigger executing twice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following trigger -

```
USE [DatabaseA]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[T_TableA_U]    Script Date: 02/17/2014 18:08:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[T_TableA_U]
on [dbo].[TableA]
after update
as
    set nocount on
    DECLARE @HistoryType    char(1) --"I"=insert, "U"=update, "D"=delete
    DECLARE @RevisionID INT
    SET @HistoryType = 'U'
    SET @RevisionID = 0


    INSERT INTO [DatabaseB].[dbo].[TableA]
            (column1_revtm, column2_revtype,
            column3_id, column4_revid, column5_type, ....)
        SELECT
            GETDATE(), @HistoryType,
            a.column1_id, @RevisionID, a.column2, ....
            FROM TableA a
            inner join inserted i on a.column1_id = i.column1_id
```

If I manually update a row in the SOURCE it creates 1 new row in the DESTINATION.  This is good.

When I use the 3rd party application I'm building this trigger on however, it's generating duplicate rows in the DESTINATION.  All data is exactly the same except for the GETDATE() which tells me it's somehow duplicating the result which the application is forcing.

So how do I get around this?  Is there a way to force a DISTINCT before the INSERT happens either in this trigger or could I create another trigger on the DESTINATION table that says if the row is a duplicate then only INSERT 1 of them?

Comment: Are there any other triggers on the table.  Also, how far apart are the GETDATEs?  If its consistently more than 3 milliseconds, then in all likelihood, the 3rd party app is doing the update twice.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - No other triggers.  I just checked on a few of the lines and in most cases the duplication is happening at 00:00.020 apart or less.  1 example below - 
`id column1_revtm
3 2014-02-16 23:12:12.373
4 2014-02-16 23:12:12.387`

Comment: Then turn on the SQL profiler and look at what's really going on.  My bet is the App is doing it twice.

Comment: k thnx.  I think it is too.  Assuming that, is there a way to get rid of the duplicate before it's inserting into the secondary table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem to be in the way the legacy application is designed.  The table I had this trigger on had a PK/FK matching to another table.  I reversed the trigger to run off the table with the FK and it works on a 1 to 1 basis with no duplicates so it would seem the legacy app updates both tables even if only 1 table is updated.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do that? I am facing the same problem and am unable to resolve it.

Comment: @Lucky This was so long ago I'm afraid I can't however I can tell you this was at the time an MSAccess Application with an MSSQL Backend.  The MSSQL Backend had triggers however within the MSAccess code there was also a trigger to copy data.  This resulted in the duplication as it was picking up the new record.  I flipped it from A -> B to B -> A so it circumvated the MSAccess condition.

Comment: Okay. Thank-you.